# UIManagedDocument CompletionHandler not executed in iOS 5.1 simulator but works on device and iOS 6.0 simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, uimanageddocument

I hope someone has some thoughts on this one...

I have a project that uses UIManagedDocument.  The first thing I do in the appDelegate is open the document.  Everything has been going fine until suddenly (nothing was changed in the code) the -openWithCompletionHandler: stopped executing the handler code.  The app works just fine on the device, but not in the simulator.  As a lark I tried running the app under the iOS 5.0 and 6.0 simulators and everything works as expected!?!

I have reinstalled xcode 4.5 and the behavior stays the same.  I deinstalled by trashing the xcode app in the applications folder.  I also deleted all the iPhone simulator files in the ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ directory.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. WTF!

Comment: Update...  Upgraded to Xcode 4.5.2 and still the same problem :-(

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038347/in-uidocument-completion-handler-never-gets-called-in-ios-5-but-works-in-ios-6 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537225/openwithcompletionhandler-prob-in-5-1-sim