# openWithCompletionHandler prob in 5.1 sim

Tags: ios, xcode, uidocument

I'm puzzled.  I'm finding that the UIDocument method openWithCompletionHandler works in the iOS 5 and IOS 6 sims, but not in the one for iOS 5.1.

Any thoughts on how I work around this?  Is it just one of those things where the sim falls down but the real environment doesn't?

Thanks.

Steve

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038347/in-uidocument-completion-handler-never-gets-called-in-ios-5-but-works-in-ios-6 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577672/uimanageddocument-completionhandler-not-executed-in-ios-5-1-simulator-but-works

Answer (score 2):

I see something similar. In `openWithCompletionHandler` the completion handler is never called. In `saveToURL`, the app freezes completely. As for you this only happens in the 5.1 simulator. 5.0 and now 6.1 are fine.