# In UIDocument completion handler never gets called in IOS 5 but works in IOS 6

Tags: ios5, uidocument

In UIDocument completion handler never gets called in IOS 5 but works in IOS6

Comment: I have similar situation, UIDocument completion handler doesn't get called on iOS 5.1, but it does on iOS 5.0 and iOS 6.0 (checked by break point inside completion handler)

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similiar thing with the UIDocument saveToURL method; the completion handler never gets called (the code seems to internally deadlock for some reason)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537225/openwithcompletionhandler-prob-in-5-1-sim & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577672/uimanageddocument-completionhandler-not-executed-in-ios-5-1-simulator-but-works